# Не могу установить phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Не могу установить phpmyadmin. Скопировал файлы, а настроить конфиг не смог. Прошу показать как прописаться, чтобы получить доступ к БД на хосте, или предложите другой вариант доступа к ней с учетом, что удаленного доступа нет.

Comment: А какой доступ есть? Конфиг покажите, что вы сделали.

Comment: Хостинг под виндой что ли?

Comment: это windows?

Comment: Расшифровка моего коммента: Установить на виндовс мне не приходилось, но в никсах это делается одним запросом.Для ubuntu: "sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin". Если фряха то точно не скажу. Имхо: качать файлы и впихивать их на сервак с последующим конфигурированием мувитон.